# create zip format whose AES password is UTF international letters

Tags: encryption, 7-zip, utf-8, aes, 7za

for reason beyond me we want to create zip format encrypted with AES-256, whose password can be International, on Linux.

If we use 7-zip, I found it works when creating 7z file, ie the following works:

```
7za a -t7z -p密码 test.7z ok.txt
```

However, the same command fails with error if creating zip file, as in the following:

```
7za a -tzip -p密码 test.zip ok.txt
```

Is there any way to solve this problem?

We don't have to stick to 7-zip command, any method that can create zip format with AES-256 password in International characters on Linux will do.

Please, for reason beyond me we can not use 7zip format.

This is surprising because I checked Python, Perl, Go, Rust, C, none of them offer (mature) module to do this, except resorting to a commercial software company Chilkat.  Details are:

- Python: only module to crate zip with AES is "pyzipper", but it does not work with non-ASCII password
- Perl: none of its free module can do zip with AES.
- Go: its module that does zip with AES is still in Alpha.
- Rust: don't see it has module that does zip with AES.
- C: there are these very interesting pages:
  https://www.winzip.com/en/support/aes-encryption/tips/
  https://github.com/abhay/gladman-aes
  However expecting us to do all the coding to implement a correct encryption program is still far fetched, due to the various issues mentioned in that Winzip webpage.

I likely missed something, grateful if you point out.

Thanks!

Comment: What software will be used for *extracting* the archive? From a quick look through the Zip format APPNOTE, it doesn't specify a concrete encoding for the password that all programs should agree on, and I suspect that's why 7zip only allows ASCII (as the "guaranteed to work" subset).

Comment: Thanks.  I was expecting Winzip, Winrar, 7-Zip etc can extact.  That Chilkat package can create such zip file with UTF international password and then extracted by 7-zip just fine.  Also Winzip can create such zip file and extract by itself just fine.  It does prompt a warning saying such password may have compatibility issue with some software.